# Maven plugin to download file

Tags: java, maven

I need to download a file from a 3rd party web server and copy it to src/main/resources whenever Maven builds something. Is there a plugin or something that does it?
It is not that file is too large.

Or is there a way to invoke a Java class that does this?

Comment: Downloading stuff to  src/main/resources sounds like a bad idea - the files there should be source code and come from your source code repo. Could you give some background, and explain why you think you need this?

Comment: What kind of file is it? Is that file needed when building? Otherwise, it could be wise to only get it when packaging your module.

Comment: @sleske This is one old project that looks into the file from classpath.

Comment: @watery This is just a file used at run time and not at compile time.

Comment: Good, you can try one of the suggested plugins. I just wanted to suggest you to configure it for the right phase, so that you don't end up with Maven downloading it too many times.

Answer (score 2):

There exists a `maven-download-plugin` which enables downloads in part of a maven build.

check this out: https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin

Answer (score 2):

There exists a `wagon-maven-plugin` for a long time.

https://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/

I would suggest to put this file which should be downloaded into a repository manager and use it as a dependency makes life easier.

Comment: if it comes to repository then one could simply use `dependency:copy-dependencies` plugin assuming that file is deployed to repository as a maven artifact

Comment: Just a guess here, but I think the OP ins't going to fetch a (regular) dependency. Would your suggestion work for generic binary files?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by a regular dependency but as for repository manager (e.g. Archiva) you can deploy any binary and generate a thin POM specification.

Comment: @SergeyPauk By regular dependency I meant jars or similar artifacts that are used in the compile phase. I'm new to Maven and I just know about POMs, jars, or bundle dependencies, I didn't knew that , i.e., a Word document could be packed as a dependency